# drop down list for an external list

Tags: external-content-type

If a guy were to want to allow a user to change data in an external list (based on an ECT of a SQL Server Table), and he had a particular field in that list (say a status field) that only needs to be in 4 specific statuses (i.e. CREATED/READY/INPROCESS/BADORDER), is there a way to put in a drop down list when they go to “edit” the record and only allow these options via a drop down list for this particular field? If so, how does one go about adding this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should crate statuses table in your SQL Server, then add association to your external content type. How to do this you can find in [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394528.aspx).